# Uploading doc file without BULK statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to insert doc file into SQL server without using Bulk statement?
Reason i need to do this because i dont have permission to use bulk load statement.

Comment: do you want to load the file or the content ? if you want to load the content what is the format of the doc file?

Comment: It will be a doc file, to be more precise it will be a resume.